# Can't get a orientation from image

Tags: javascript, exif-js

I'm working on a solution to fix an issue in which images made from certain phones appear either sideways or upside down due to them having orientation in the exif data. So far I have that I get orientation, but this variable in not passed back in time for the next rotation steps.

```
function getOrientation(image){
    let ort = 1;
    EXIF.getData(image, function () {
        ort = EXIF.getTag(this, 'Orientation');
    });
    return ort;
}
```

The value from ort is later used in combination with a canvas to rotate the uploaded image. As shown below, but each change makes the value become 1 or undefined.

```
    let orientation = getOrientation(files);
    let data = rotateImage(files, orientation);
```

What is the best way to pass the variable called ort back to the function that made a call to getOrientation()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple things I was able to fix it by making orietation a global variable and let the rotateImage have a delayed execution with setTimeout. By doing this getOrientation can finish and rotateImage can use the let orientation after the timeout is over.